# GitHub Pages Failed to load resource

Tags: angular, github-pages, bootstrap-4

I am trying to host an Angular application with Bootstrap 4 on GitHub Pages with `angular-cli-ghpages` at https://ewoutg.github.io/ePortfolio/ but I run into several of these errors:

```
Failed to load resource: styles.05418b2b9d65514cb185.bundle.css the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
```

I do have a Dist folder with that resource in:

[image: screenshot of folder structure]

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Thanks alot! This fixed it I've been trying to find a solution all day long. My image is not found but that's fixable. Thanks!

Comment: Can I mark your answer as the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems your problem is related with case sensitivity. Try the following base href

```
<base href="https://ewoutg.github.io/ePortfolio/">
```

Here is used capital `P`